# In how many ways can $2$ doors be selected from $3$ doors for entering and leaving a room?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $2$ doors be selected from $3$ doors for entering and leaving a room?

Options for answers are: $1, 3, 6, 9, 12$.

Since we have 3 doors and we should pick 2 doors for ENTERING and LEAVING then the answer is $C_3^2\times 2!=3!=6.$ That it my answer. However, the correct answer is $3$. But I suppose that $3$ is incorrect.

Can anyone explain it please?

Comment: Presumably, they interpret entering through door A and leaving through door B to be the same as entering through door B and leaving through door A.

Comment: @Kajelad, I think that above problem has some problems with wording.

Comment: I have no idea what the question means. "For entering and leaving the room"? What the heck? What does that even mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you choose $2$ out of the  $3$ doors then you can enter through  $1$ and leave through the other.   So $\binom3{2}=3$.  They say nothing about the order.  So it's combinations, not permutations. ..